# WooCommerce show custom stock message when a size variant is selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have this logic on my product detail page:
[image]

I've added this to the `functions.php` file for the active child theme:

```
// Enqueue JavaScript for handling variation change
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_variation_stock_script');
function custom_variation_stock_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-variation-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-variation.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}

// Add a placeholder for stock quantity display
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_stock_quantity', 25);
function display_stock_quantity() {
    echo '<div id="stock_quantity_display" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>';
}
```

`custom-variation.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.variations_form').on('found_variation', function(event, variation) {
        console.error('CHECK VARIATION');
        if (variation.is_in_stock && variation.stock_quantity != null) {
            $('#stock_quantity_display').text('In stock: ' + variation.stock_quantity);
        } else {
            $('#stock_quantity_display').text('Out of stock');
        }
    }).on('reset_data', function() {
        $('#stock_quantity_display').text('');
    });
});
```

The code is executed when I change the dropdown, I see the error being logged.
However, the element #stock_quantity_display is not inserted.

**UPDATE 1**

**functions.php of child theme**

```
<?php

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [] );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 20 );

function avada_lang_setup() {
    $lang = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages';
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'Avada', $lang );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'avada_lang_setup' );


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_variation_stock_script');
function custom_variation_stock_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-variation-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-variation.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}

//hide specific attributes from "Additional information tab" on Woo Tabs

add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'exclude_attribute_from_attribute_table', 9999, 2 );
function exclude_attribute_from_attribute_table( $product_attributes, $product ) {
   if ( isset( $product_attributes[ 'attribute_pa_ring-size' ] ) ) unset( $product_attributes[ 'attribute_pa_ring-size' ] );
   return $product_attributes;
}


// Add some extra variation data to the variable product form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_product_variation_stock_quantity', 10, 3);
function add_product_variation_stock_quantity( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    return array_merge($data, array('stock_qty' => $variation->get_stock_quantity()));
}

// Add a placeholder for stock quantity display
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_stock_quantity', 25);
function display_stock_quantity() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_type('variable') ) {
        return; // Exit if it's not a variable product
    }

    wc_enqueue_js("const a = '#stock_quantity_display';
    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        $(a).html(data.availability_html);
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(a).html('');
    });");

    echo '<div id="stock_quantity_display" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>';
}
```

**custom-variation.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.error('CUSTOM JS');
    $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function(event, variation) {
        console.error('CHECK VARIATION');
        if (variation.is_in_stock && variation.stock_quantity != null) {
            $('#stock_quantity_display').text('In stock: ' + variation.stock_quantity);
        } else {
            $('#stock_quantity_display').text('Out of stock');
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function() {
        $('#stock_quantity_display').text('');
    });
});
```

When I load the product detail page "CUSTOM JS" is logged to the console and when I change the product variation the line "CHECK VARIATION" is also logged.

However, when I right-click view source and look for element stock_quantity_display it's not there. How can I debug why the element is not injected?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `variation.stock_quantity` defined, so you need to add it with:

```php
// Add some extra variation data to the variable product form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_product_variation_stock_quantity', 10, 3);
function add_product_variation_stock_quantity( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    return array_merge($data, array('stock_qty' => $variation->get_stock_quantity()));
}
```

Also, in your jQuery code use `show_variation` and `hide_variation` instead of `found_variation` and `reset_data`.

Now your code can be optimized in a unique function that will replace all your code:

```php
// Add a placeholder for stock quantity display
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_stock_quantity', 25);
function display_stock_quantity() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_type('variable') ) {
        return; // Exit if it's not a variable product
    }

    $instock_txt = __('In stock:', 'woocommerce');
    $outofstock_txt = __('Out of stock', 'woocommerce');

    wc_enqueue_js("const a = '#stock_quantity_display';
    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        const q = data.stock_qty;
        if (data.is_in_stock && q != null) {
            $(a).html('{$instock_txt} '+q);
        } else {
            $(a).html('{$outofstock_txt}');
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(a).html('');
    });");

    echo '<div id="stock_quantity_display" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

Now you could use the built-in WooCommerce product availability instead like, replacing all previous code with the following:

```php
// Add a placeholder for stock quantity display
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_stock_quantity', 25);
function display_stock_quantity() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_type('variable') ) {
        return; // Exit if it's not a variable product
    }

    wc_enqueue_js("const a = '#stock_quantity_display';
    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        $(a).html(data.availability_html);
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(a).html('');
    });");

    echo '<div id="stock_quantity_display" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion does update the correct quantity in my HTML, but it has this class (not defined , so does not display. Is that a woocommerce setting? `.fusion-woo-cart.hide-stock .stock, .fusion-woo-cart.hide-stock .woocommerce-variation-availability {
    display: none;
}` defined in sheet `/wp-content/uploads/fusion-styles/d258638836fe87c0f7edfafb35325070.min.css?ver=3.11.5`
I'd rather not change the sheet, but instead configure a Woocommerce setting. A Google search does not help me

Comment: You can see it live here: https://www.verlanglijst.com/product/mens-ring-vanguard-with-mystic-symbols/

Comment: I tried both options now but I don't see element with id `stock_quantity_display` being inserted in the HTML when I change the option.
What I notice is this line in your code `woocommerce_single_product_summary`, but I use variable products. Does that matter?

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_single_product_summary` work on single product pages for all product types. My code is tested and works in last WooCommerce version under WooCommerce Storefront theme. In your case, maybe some other code added by you, some plugin or your theme is making trouble.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my update 1, how can I check why element `stock_quantity_display` is never inserted? I do see that the HTML in element `woocommerce-variation-availability` is being updated when I change the SKU.

Comment: I don't know why stock_quantity_display is never inserted, so it means that `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook doesn't work, maybe because you are using product Block, or maybe it can be due to your theme own customizations and own hooks…